# Common Lisp type specifiers

Tags: performance, common-lisp, typing

I recently started fiddling with type specifiers to improve code efficiency. [This](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node45.html#SECTION00810000000000000000) is a list of all the type specifier symbols in the Common Lisp standard.

I can't see the tree through the forest.

Could anyone give (or point to) a short description of the different type specifiers, and when one would use them?

Though I'm interested to learn about all of them, my direct interest goes out to the differences between number related types (fixnum, bignum, float, single-float, short-float, etc...)

Comment: It should be noted that specifying types should not be the first step in improving performance. Usually these are not required, except for tight loops that are heavy on calculations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CLtl2 describes a version of Common Lisp before it was standardized. Don't use it as a reference, there are various differences to the standard.

Use the Common Lisp Hyperspec, which is based on the ANSI Common Lisp Standard.

The types of Common Lisp are described in the HyperSpec here: [4.2.3 Type Specifiers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/04_bc.htm). The various types are linked from there.

Answer (score 6):

Here ia a typical implementation:

`fixnum` is a small integer that fits in a machine register; it is the fastest integer

`bignum` is an integer of unlimited size

`double-float` is an IEEE double precision floating point number; it may be very fast, too, depending on your computer

`single-float` is an IEEE single precision floating point number; it has less range and precision and may be slower than double, but takes less memory

`short-float` and `long-float` are often mapped to the two above types, but may also be different, again, depending on your CL implementation